# Chartjs blocks jumping to a section in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I have included a canvas element in one of my views and it is filled with statistics. The statistic is displayed by chartjs. In my navbar I have a link to a certain position in my view. This link looks like this:

```
<a class="drpDownLnk nav-link dropdown-header" href="#mySection">go to mySection</a>
```

My canvas element looks like this:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

And this is how I bind chartjs to my canvas element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        let chart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

        let termAnzChart = new Chart(chart, {
                type: 'line',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)',
                data: {
                    labels: [
                        @Model.myLabels
                    ],
                    datasets: [{
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                            data: [
                                @Model.myData
                            ]
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                autoSkip: false,
                                maxRotation: 90,
                                minRotation: 90
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
        });
    });
```

Unfortunately my link only works the second time you click and not the first time. What can be the reason for this? Without the chartjs part the link works fine. Only if I include chartjs the link works only with the second click. I have already tried to remove the instruction `$(document).ready()`. But the problem still occurs. Can anyone help?

Subsequent note: This error occurs only in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have now dealt with the problem intensively. The problem occurs only in Google Chrome. Even IE 11 can handle it. Also Firefox and EDGE have no problem with it. Furthermore, the problem does not occur when debugging through the JavaScript code on the client side with Google Chrome. So the problem only occurs if you use Google Chrome and if you are not in debug mode. I have already notified Google about the problem, because I think this is a Google Chrome bug. So this stackoverflow issue is closed for now.